# Opening maps with current location and directions in iOS 6

Tags: google-maps, ios5, ios6, directions, ios6-maps

I am building an app that can open the Maps app with directions from the user's current position to another position. The code looks like this:

```
- (id)resolveDirectionsFromCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)startCoordinate toCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)endCoordinate
{
    NSString* url = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=%f,%f&daddr=%f,%f",
                 startCoordinate.latitude, startCoordinate.longitude,
                 endCoordinate.latitude, endCoordinate.longitude];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: [NSURL URLWithString: url]];

    return nil;
}
```

Thos works well in iOS 5.x. In iOS 6, however, this brings up Safari instead, since Maps no longer uses Google Maps.

Does anyone know which URL I should call in iOS 6?

Comment: iOS6 is currently still under NDA and you should not ask related questions anywhere but within the Apple developer forum.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The [Apple Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Articles/MapLinks.html) recommends using the equivalent maps.apple.com URL Scheme

so use

```
http://maps.apple.com/maps?saddr=%f,%f&daddr=%f,%f
```

instead of

```
http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=%f,%f&daddr=%f,%f
```

to be backwards compatible your code would be

```
    NSString* versionNum = [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion];
    NSString *nativeMapScheme = @"maps.apple.com";
    if ([versionNum compare:@"6.0" options:NSNumericSearch] == NSOrderedAscending){
        nativeMapScheme = @"maps.google.com";
    }
    NSString* url = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://%@/maps?saddr=%f,%f&daddr=%f,%f", nativeMapScheme startCoordinate.latitude, startCoordinate.longitude,
                 endCoordinate.latitude, endCoordinate.longitude];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
```

Alternatively you could also use the `maps://saddr=%f,%f&daddr=%f,%f`scheme but it does not appear support the full range of parameters.

Comment: This is wrong, you need to use ll= for latitude and longitude and saddr and daddr for the city names

Comment: @sreecharan the code above is correct for getting directions from a start and destination location (you can use lat/lon or address). the ll parameter is used when you would like to centre the map at a particular lat/lon

Answer (score 8):

Use `+ (BOOL)openMapsWithItems:(NSArray *)mapItems launchOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions` method. From the [MKMapItem Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapItem_class/Reference/Reference.html) :

> You use this method to pass one or more map items to the Maps app. For example, you might use this method to ask the Maps app to display location-based search results generated by your app. Maps displays pins at each location you specify and uses the contents of each map item object to display additional information.

Answer (score 2):

```
// Check for iOS 6
Class mapItemClass = [MKMapItem class];
if (mapItemClass && [mapItemClass     respondsToSelector:@selector(openMapsWithItems:launchOptions:)]) 
{
    // Create an MKMapItem to pass to the Maps app
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = 
                CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(16.775, -3.009);
    MKPlacemark *placemark = [[MKPlacemark alloc] initWithCoordinate:coordinate 
                                        addressDictionary:nil];
    MKMapItem *mapItem = [[MKMapItem alloc] initWithPlacemark:placemark];
    [mapItem setName:@"My Place"];

    // Set the directions mode to "Driving"
    // Can use MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeWalking instead
    NSDictionary *launchOptions = @{MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeKey :   MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeDriving };
    // Get the "Current User Location" MKMapItem
    MKMapItem *currentLocationMapItem = [MKMapItem mapItemForCurrentLocation];
   // Pass the current location and destination map items to the Maps app
   // Set the direction mode in the launchOptions dictionary
   [MKMapItem openMapsWithItems:@[currentLocationMapItem, mapItem] 
                launchOptions:launchOptions];
   }
```

That is all :)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend checking out [CMMapLauncher](https://github.com/citymapper/CMMapLauncher), a mini-library that I built to launch Apple, Google, and other iOS mapping apps with a specific mapping request.  With CMMapLauncher, the code to get the directions in your question would be:

```
[CMMapLauncher launchMapApp:CMMapAppAppleMaps
          forDirectionsFrom:[CMMapPoint mapPointWithName:@"Origin"
                                              coordinate:startCoordinate]
                         to:[CMMapPoint mapPointWithName:@"Destination"
                                              coordinate:endCoordinate]];
```

As you can see, it also encapsulates the version checking required between iOS 6 & others.